# Clojure function will not compile

Tags: clojure

Please excuse my complete lack of knowledge, but why doesn't this function compile?

```
(defn add-onehundred
  [num]
    (+ num 100))

  (add-onehundred 5)
```

I get this error thrown in the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling at (/private/var/folders/ls/j5fjkkb96mx340pb_gm12t740000gn/T/form-init13922061526950471210.clj:1:126).
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7647)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot find anything to run for: clojure-noob.core
        at user$eval140.invokeStatic(form-init13922061526950471210.clj:1)
        at user$eval140.invoke(form-init13922061526950471210.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7166)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
        ... 12 more
```

full code as in the editor here, when main is commented out it will not compile, when it isn't commented out `add-onehundred` returns nothing:

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

; (defn -main
;   "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
;   [& args]
;   (println "Hello, Mate"))

(defn add-onehundred
  [num]
    (+ num 100))

(add-onehundred 5)
```

Comment: Works fine for me, what error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Please post the error message. The code looks fine superficially. The error is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks - have posted error above

Comment: @tommmmmmmy How are you running this? Note what the error says. You haven't supplied a `-main` function. Unless you're running this as a script, you need to supply a `main` just like you would in Java. If you run this code in a REPL, it will work fine

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks - when I supply the main function `add-onehundred` doesn't return anything but `main` does - the code compiles successfully.

Comment: @tommmmmmmy Are you running `(println (add-onehundred 5))` inside of the `-main`?

Comment: I would run this in a REPL, but I want to use multiline code. Running it with command `lein run` and editing the code with VS Code.

Comment: Updated post above

Comment: Again, you need to call the function inside the main and print out the result. Having the code at the bottom doesn't print it out unless you're in a REPL environment.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, so *everything* needs to be inside main? And with a REPL I can only create a new line with a slash? I just want to run a function :)

Comment: Not everything no. Just code you want to run when the program runs. See [here](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/eb1a172756ae8a8678b2255b350fabed)

Comment: And I recommend using an environment like IntelliJ with the Cursive plugin. The REPL is much easier to use than most. It easily allows multi-line executions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ty kind sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, you're trying to run this with:

```
lein run
```

and you have the following in your `project.clj` file:

```
:main clojure-noob.core
```

or:

```
:main ^:skip-aot clojure-noob.core
```

This tell Leiningen to look for a `-main` function in the `clojure-noob.core` namespace in order to "run" your new application -- but you've commented it out, so Leiningen cannot find it, hence "Cannot find anything to run for: clojure-noob.core".

Uncomment your `-main` and have it call `add-onehundred`and print the result. Note that functions in Clojure must be defined (or at least declared) before they are used, so your code will end up looking like this:

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn add-onehundred
  [num]
  (+ num 100))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println (add-onehundred 5)))
```

`lein run` should run your app and print `105`.